# Check multiple conditions when button is pressed

Tags: c#

I am writing a registration form at the moment. When I click the button I want the form to check several factors in order to continue on and save the data to the database. If there is an error I have three labels that will display the errors. So, when the button is clicked I want it to check and make sure the textboxes are not empty, and then if they are empty, post that text to one of the three labels. And then if the password fields do not match or are empty, add that to another label. And I also want to check to make sure that the password meets length requirements

The problem I am having is that once it gets done one if statement, it basically stops. So I added a else if statement but that didn't really help at all either. Is there something I am missing?

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     checkBoxes();
     string err();

     if (emptyBoxes.Count != 0) 
     {
        err = string.Join(", ", emptyBoxes) + " cannot be empty";
        lblError.Text = err;
     }
     else if (!txtPassword.Text.Equals(txtPwdConf.Text))
     {
          lblError2.Text = "Passwords do not match!";
     }
     else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text))
     {
          String password = txtPassword.Text;

          Match pw = Regex.Match(password, @"((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A - Z])(?=.*\W).{ 8,50})", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

            if (!pw.Success)
            {
                lblError3.Text = "Passowrd is not valid.";
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` only instead of `if else`:

```
 if (emptyBoxes.Count != 0) 
 {
    err = string.Join(", ", emptyBoxes) + " cannot be empty";
    lblError.Text = err;
 }
 if (!txtPassword.Text.Equals(txtPwdConf.Text))
 {
      lblError2.Text = "Passwords do not match!";
 }
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text))
 {
      String password = txtPassword.Text;

      Match pw = Regex.Match(password, @"((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A - Z])(?=.*\W).{ 8,50})", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

        if (!pw.Success)
        {
            lblError3.Text = "Passowrd is not valid.";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically says:

1. If empty boxes count is not zero, do `A`
2. If empty box count is zero **and** txtPassword does not equal txtPwdConf, do `B`
3. If empty box count is zero, and txtPassword is equal to txtPwdConf **and** txtPassword is not null or empty, do `C`

Do you see the problem?

Your if statements are all mutually exclusive.  Meaning if one is triggered, none of the others *can be triggered*.  This is because you are using `else if` statements instead of `if`.

If you change your code to solely use `if` statements you will notice a big difference:

```
if (emptyBoxes.Count != 0) 
{
    err = string.Join(", ", emptyBoxes) + " cannot be empty";
    lblError.Text = err;
}
if (!txtPassword.Text.Equals(txtPwdConf.Text))
{
    lblError2.Text = "Passwords do not match!";
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text))
{
    String password = txtPassword.Text;
    Match pw = Regex.Match(password, @"((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A - Z])(?=.*\W).{ 8,50})", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    if (!pw.Success)
    {
        lblError3.Text = "Passowrd is not valid.";
    }
}
```

This code is like saying:

1. If empty boxes count is not zero, do `A`
2. **Regardless of empty box count**. If txtPassword is not equal to txtPwdConf, do `B`
3. **Regardless of empty box count, or txtPassword matching txtPwdConf**.  If txtPassword is not null or empty

Comment: Ahh! I understand now! Something so simple! Thanks so much guys! One more question. I want to save it to a database like I said. So if all of those if statements come back good, how do I go about triggering it to save to the database? I changed them to if and it works, but it will save to the database regardless. Do I have to add another if or else statement?

Comment: If you want to save to a database no matter what, then just put that code after all your if statements.  If you only want to save to the database if there are no errors, then do what I just said, but put `return;` inside all your ifs so that the method returns if there is an error (meaning your save to database code will not run if there is an error)

Comment: Now that I put the returns in the if statements, it wont save to the database at all. When I click the button it does nothing, not even an error message